# Statistical analysis of data within my genealogy program?

Tags: statistics, software-recommendations

I wish to find a program which will allow me to pose certain specific questions and have my genealogy program answer them such as:

- What is the average age of a named person's direct male ancestors?
- What is the average age of a named person's direct female ancestors?
- Who was the longest lived such person?
- What was the longest marriage?
- Who married the most times?
- Who had the most children?

Is anybody aware of a program that does all this at the press of a button having set up the report.

All the standard genealogy programs do not seem to do this.

My Heritage has been suggested but I do not wish to publish my tree on that site.  I need something simple.

Comment: This would depend very much on the format of your genealogy database.  GEDCOM/XML/etc?  There are any number of XML parsers out there,

Comment: A few years ago, there were some GEDCOM-to-HTML programs that you could use to publish a tree on-line or to use on your home computer, that had similar reports linked to the home page. (Although they tended to look at the whole database, not subsets). It's been a while since I checked which are still available.

Answer (score 5):

The queries that you are asking for can be easily performed by Family Historian, it has several queries that cover most of what you want and you can create your own. There is a 30 day free trial of Family Historian that you could try that allows you to run the queries. It is available from the [Family Historian website](http://www.family-historian.co.uk/downloads/free-30-day-trial). There are also some user generated queries available on the Family Historian Users Group that cover other data analysis not included in the standard query set. This is a  screenshot of the standard inbuilt queries:
[image]

Once you have run the query you can sort on any column and that will show what you want.

Gigatrees used to supply a report with some of this information from your Gedcom file but it seems as though that is discontinued, you may be able to find an archived copy of it with an internet search.

FT Analyzer also does some of what you want. It is available for download from [CodePlex](https://ftanalyzer.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I will try Family Historian as I need soomething straightforward and simple for a technological ignoramus.

Comment: As you are going to try Family Historian make sure you join the users group too it is free. Join at https://fhug.org.uk/ the forum and the knowledgebase are key areas for help.

Answer (score 4):

A free program that provides some useful statistics is [My Family Tree by Chronoplex Software](https://chronoplexsoftware.com/myfamilytree/index.htm).

On [their description of their Statistics](https://chronoplexsoftware.com/myfamilytree/help/statistics.htm), they say: "The Statistics view displays a variety of information panels and charts.  Each tab contains a different set of interesting charts and facts."

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Gigatrees (http://gigatrees.com) can provide the first two of these broken out by century on its statistics page and the third as part of its data validation report.

Answer (score 1):

Some of what you want can be done with the analytics pages generated by ged2site - it should be easy to add the other reports.  See https://github.com/nigelhorne/ged2site

For my own family tree you can see the results at https://genealogy.nigelhorne.com/cgi-bin/page.fcgi?page=graphs